# Take string from text file, evaluate the variables once returned VBA/SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel

I grab SQL code from a text from the file with vba using the following code (no problems in this section):

```
Function ReturnSql(filepath As String) As String

Dim TextFile As Integer
Dim FileContent As String

'Determine the next file number available for use by the FileOpen function

TextFile = FreeFile

'Open the text file
    Open filepath For Input As TextFile

'Store file content inside a variable
    FileContent = Input(LOF(TextFile), TextFile)
    ReturnSql = FileContent
'Close Text File
Close TextFile

End Function
```

I then drop the code into an adodb connection in VBA.  All well and good.  However i want to add a variable.  if this was all in vba it'd look something like this:

```
sub RunSqlWithVariable
dim strSQL as string
strSQL = "SELECT ClientTerm FROM ClientTable WHERE ClientID = '" & strClient & "';"
'Put this into an adodb connection etc
end sub
```

I have stored SQL procedures in a textfile.  these resemble this:

```
SELECT ClientTerm
FROM ClientTable
WHERE ClientID = '" & strClient & ";'"
```

however i can't get the variable strClient to evaluate (not sure about my phrasing here).  Is there a function for this?  Or should i just use find and replace?

EDIT: for clarity, i want to bring back the above string and get the variable to show a value i pass it in the VBA section of the code, so input from SQL.txt would be as immediately above, the string i would like to see in vba below:

```
SELECT ClientTerm
FROM ClientTable
WHERE ClientID = 'Opera Winfrey';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim sql As String
    Dim sClient As String

    sClient = "Sid"

    strClient = ReturnSql("C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Desktop\Sid.txt")

    strClient = Replace(strClient, "strClient", Chr(34) & sClient & Chr(34))

    Debug.Print strClient
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
SELECT ClientTerm
FROM ClientTable
WHERE ClientID = '" & "Sid" & ";'"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, not really though, unless im misunderstanding what you have here; i' d like the output "SELECT ClientTerm FROM ClientTable WHERE ClientID = 'Sid'" so i can query a db, does that make sense?  i'll loook at editing my original question

Comment: `strClient` in the `Debug.Print strClient` already has `SELECT ClientTerm FROM ClientTable WHERE ClientID = 'Sid'` after the variable is evaluated. You can use that string to query the DB.

Comment: Yep cool, based on this i actually changed the characters so that i was just using a = Replace(strSql, "strClient", strClient), but method worked well.  Thanks very much.